# Is the Languague which contains all TMs which write the blank symbol at firs by the given input w decidable?

Tags: turing-machines, undecidability, semi-decidability, turing-completeness

Consider the problem of determining whether a Turing machine M on an input w writes the blank symbol at first. Is this decidable ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just simulate $M$ on $w$ and check to see if it wrote the blank symbol at first